# How does i["string"] work as a condition statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements, obfuscation

Check [this obfuscated code](http://www.ioccc.org/1984/anonymous.c) in IOCCC. I'm trying to understand this.

```
int i;main(){for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"];read('-'-'-',i+++"hell\
o, world!\n",'/'/'/'));}read(j,i,p){write(j/p+p,i---j,i/i);}
```

Means:

```
int i;
main()
{
    for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"];read('-'-'-',i+++"hello, world!\n",'/'/'/'));
}
read(j,i,p)
{
    write(j/p+p,i---j,i/i);
}
```

Please explain me this : `i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]`

How this works as a condition statement here?

Comment: `i[foo]` == `*(i + foo)`

Comment: `X` as condition statement is the same as `(X) != 0`

Comment: i["]<i;++i){--i;}"] == "]<i;++i){--i;}"[i]. i==0.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C indexing is kinda funky. `a[b]` is roughly equivalent to `*(a+b)` (with `a` degrading to a pointer to the first element). But addition is commutative, so `a[b]` and `b[a]` do the same thing. Thus:

```
i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]
```

is really just:

```
"]<i;++i){--i;}"[i]
```

but the reordering obfuscates by making it look like a normalish for loop if you miss the quotes. Since all values in the string are non-zero (and therefore "true") except for the `NUL` terminator, the loop would end when `i` was equal to the length of that string literal.

Comment: And "]<i;++i){--i;}"[i] == ']'

Comment: @RichardPennington: Well, initially. `i` is changing value during execution. So the first check, when `i` is `0`, sure, it's `]`, but later checks `i` is incrementing. Doesn't really matter what it happens to produce; all that matters is zero or non-zero, and all but the `NUL` terminator of a string is non-zero.